With DNF repoquery, how can one tell installed packages from available packages?
rpm outputs install time when corresponding tag is included.
rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\t%{INSTALLTIME}\n"

prints for example 1719228733 at the end.
But when I run the same query through DNF, the corresponding field is empty.
dnf repoquery -all --qf "%{NAME}|\t%{installtime}|"

prints a single tab gap between the 2x pipes at the end, both for the installed and available packages.
DNF on my system supports these tags. Which of them can indicate whether a package is installed or not?
arch, 
buildtime, 
conflicts, 
debug_name, 
description, 
downloadsize, 
epoch, 
evr,
installsize,
installtime, 
license, 
name,
obsoletes, 
provides, 
reason
release, 
reponame (repoid), 
requires, 
size, 
source_debug_name,
source_name, 
sourcerpm,
summary, 
url, 
version,


It seems that %{installtime} only works when using the --installed selector, like this:
dnf repoquery --queryformat "%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\t%{installtime}" --installed

When the --installed selector is omitted, the installtime var is not populated.
Also see https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/issues/1881.
By the way, dnf 4.15 has a regression for uppercase use of the queryformat variable INSTALLTIME, see https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2023-308ef1c754#comment-2979552. In that case, you may use installtime instead.

This is very unfortunate because there is no way to tell which package is installed or not. Since dnf repoquery --available shows both installed and available packages, I cannot tell which is installed because installetime is not populated. Huh? This turns the task of figuring out what is installed and what is not into a 2-step process that dnfs general sloooooooowness extends to painful lengths. What were they thinking?

I agree. Some of it seems to be due to compatibility with yum, also see: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/issues/1881. Adapted answer to include that link.
